# Trying to get Bar Chart to Disappear and then have another Reappear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 data visualization and I'm trying to get my first bar chart to disappear and then have a new one appear exactly where the last one was. My problem is the second one is getting overlayed right above the first one so everything gets muddled up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    var data = [{

            "name": "text",
            "value": 2,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 44,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 20,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 18,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 12,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 9,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 7,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 6,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 5,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 4,
    },


    ];

        var margin = {
        top: 15,
        right: 35,
        bottom: 15,
        left: 115
    };

    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    //var startBar2010 = 
    startBarChart.append("g").attr("class","bar2010");


    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        //.attr("align","center")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 
    margin.top + ")"); 
        //.attr("transform", "translate(" + 200 + "," + (-500) + ")"); 

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .1)
        .domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        }));

    //make y axis to show bar names
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        //no tick marks
        .tickSize(0)
        .orient("left");

    var gy = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .transition().delay(delay*1).ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(1000)
        .call(yAxis);

    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

    //append rects
    bars.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x",  -500)
        .attr("y",  -25)
        .attr("width", 0)
        .attr("height", 35)
        .transition().delay(delay*1).ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(1000)
        //.transition().delay(delay*1).duration(2500) 
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name);
        })
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return x(d.value); 
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "16px") 
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
        .text("Do I Work ?");

        bars.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("y", -42)
        .attr("x", -520)
        .transition().delay(delay*1).ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(1000)
        //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 + 4;
        })
        //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.value) + 3;
        })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;

        });
```

I thought the following code would clear everything for the follow up bar chart

```
    bars.selectAll("g")
    //.transition().delay(delay*3).duration(1000)
    .transition().delay(delay*1.7).duration(1000) 
    .style("opacity",0)
    .call(endall, function() {
        bars.selectAll("g")
            .remove();
    });
```

Here is second bar chart data and chart:

```
var dataTwo = [{

            "name": "text",
            "value": 2,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 44,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 20,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 18,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 12,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 9,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 7,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 6,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 5,
    },
        {
            "name": "text",
            "value": 4,
    },


    ];


    var margin = {
        top: 15,
        right: 35,
        bottom: 15,
        left: 115
    };

    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    //var startBar2010 = 
    startBarChart.append("g").attr("class","bar2010");

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        //.attr("align","center")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 
        margin.top + ")"); 
        //.attr("transform", "translate(" + 200 + "," + (-500) + ")"); 

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain([0, d3.max(dataTwo, function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .1)
        .domain(dataTwo.map(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        }));

    //make y axis to show bar names
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        //no tick marks
        .tickSize(0)
        .orient("left");

    var gy = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")

    .transition().delay(delay*2.1).ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(1000)
        .call(yAxis); 

    // Update with new values

    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(dataTwo) 
        .enter()
        .append("g"); 

    //append rects
    bars.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x",  -500)
        .attr("y",  -25)
        .attr("width", 0)
        .attr("height", 35)

      .transition().delay(delay*2.1).ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(1000)
        //.transition().delay(delay*1).duration(2500)
        //.selection().delay(delay*1).duration(2500) 
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name)
        })
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return x(d.value)
        });

        bars.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("y", -42)
        .attr("x", -520)

    .transition().delay(delay*2.1).ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(1000)
        //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 + 4;
        })
        //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.value) + 3;
        })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;

        });
```

Comment: A fully reproducible example or fiddle would make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the combination of `enter().append()` is used in D3.js to create DOM elements to reflect dataset elements that don't yet exist in the DOM, likewise the `exit().remove()` combination is used to remove those DOM elements.

What you will want to do, then, is to have a DOM element acting as a container which you use as the root of your D3 manipulations. Generally, we have a `div` to which we add the chart's SVG - but you should know which element this is, whether `body`, a `div` or something else. Everything that you add into that container, should be removed by 2 steps:

1. Implementing your `exit().remove()` as described below.
2. Clearing your entire dataset currently bound to that set of elements.

This is [a useful description](https://d3indepth.com/enterexit/). Mike Bostock (D3.js's author) [has a diagram](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) clarifying exactly what `enter`, `exit` and `update` mean; "elements" here means "DOM elements", while "data" means "data array elements":

[image]